# Have a shared library for assets in nx and next 13

Tags: next.js, nrwl-nx

I want to have a shared library for assets in my nx monorepo we are both using next js in both projects.

I read the docs that you can use:

```
    "assets": [
      {
        "input": "libs/my-lib/public",
        "glob": "**/*",
        "output": "./.."
      }
    ],
```

But for some reason it just doesn't work. It states a 404 for my images when I import them like this. Not sure if this is also the way to go though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems if you add this in project.json you just need to do an npm run build and nx would copy and paste your images immediately.